# Foursquare Places JSON data not showing in the list View

Tags: android, json, listview, foursquare

I'm trying to parse Foursquare places into android application and i got success as i can view the data in Logcat but listview is not showing any data.

here is the code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16910648/foursquare-places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have posted your code here since it would be more readable. I can't find anything obvious in your code, except that it might be your venuelist that is the problem. I'm uncertain if a SimpleAdapter can handle a ArrayList with HashMaps properly. Have you tried putting any other information to the adapter?

Try putting a prefixed string[] to your adapter and see if anything comes up or write your own adapter to the ListView, that's what i recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, let me try.

Comment: Post your solution here if you find one :)